# Spring boot does not editing record in to mysql

Tags: spring, spring-boot

when i updating the records via postman record not updating it will create a new record i don't know why.i attached screenshot below along with code what i tried so far.i have attched the controller,service,
entity,repository.
i am tring this since yesterday problem not solved please some one will help me to solve

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lUtm.jpg)

**EmployeeController**

```
@PutMapping("/edit/{id}")

    private Employee update(@RequestBody Employee employees,@PathVariable(name = "id") long id)   
    {  
        Employee emp = services.get(id);
       services.saveOrUpdate(emp);  
       return employees;  
    }
```

**Services**

```
//updating a record  
    //updating a record  
 public void update(Employee employees, int id)   
 {  
     repo.save(employees);  
 }
```

**Repository**

```
    @Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee,Long>  {

}
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Records")
public class Employee {
    
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name="fname")
    private String fname;
    
    @Column(name="lname")
    private String lname;
    
    @Column(name="city")
    private String  city;
    
    
    @Column(name="phone")
    private String phone;
    
    @Column(name="salary")
    private String salary;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(String salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to set the ID of the entity when updating. Hibernate / JPA checks if the ID is set. If true => `UPDATE`, otherwise `CREATE`. Based on your provided code there is no line where the `ID` from your `PUT` Mapping path is assigned to the entity you want to update. Therefore a new entity is created all the time.

Comment: can you write the code it is easy to understand

Comment: i edited code now result .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' not supported]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This an example of UPDATE and it worked for me.

```
//HTTP PUT 
@PutMapping("/owners/{id}")
public void updateOwner(@RequestBody Owner owner, @PathVariable int id) {
    owner.setId(id);
    ownerRepos.save(owner);
}
```

I used the CrudRepository too.

Also I notice that you call services.saveOrUpdate(emp) but at the same time you showed us "public void update(Employee employees, int id)" below. If'd better if you could show the definition of the method saveOrUpdate()

Answer (score 0):

`SaveOrUpdate` uses the ID of the object to determine if the object is the same or new. When updating, you're not considering the ID of the employee. You should first fetch the Object from DB and update the same object. The updates should take place on a persistent object

Comment: can you write the code it is easy to understand

Comment: i edited code now result .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' not supported]

Comment: @raduba u can also use `postmapping` for updating the data

Comment: not work if i use above code instead of Put mapping to postmapping record not updating addding